# Listview - adding data

Tags: c#, listview

So, trying to use the ListView and fill it with data.

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("Test");
item.SubItems.Add("1");
item.SubItems.Add("2");
MyListView.Items.Add(item);
```

Now, I haven been searching and reading and I feel so stupid cause I just can't figure out how the items/subitems work.

The above code won't do anything :/

> ```
>        foreach (Ingredient o in list)
>         {
>             ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
>
>             lvi.Text = o.iName;
>             lvi.SubItems.Add(o.iUnit);
>             lvi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(o.iCalories));
>             listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
>
>         }
> ```

It works now, BUT, I no longer have access to the items.
How do I know get back an item, or change stuff in an item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
viewList.View = View.Details;

viewList.Columns.Add("Key");
viewList.Columns.Add("Value");

ListViewItem lvi1 = new ListViewItem();

lvi1.Text = "Key";
lvi1.SubItems.Add("Value");
viewList.Items.Add(lvi1);
```

Comment: Wait a second, I know what's wrong here.
MyListView isn't connected to the listview in my form?
How do I do this?

Comment: Is your `ListView` control not in the same class as your Form? It certainly should be.

Answer (score 1):

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
        listView1.View = View.Details;

        List<Ingredient> list = controller.FindAllIngredients();

        foreach (Ingredient o in list)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

            lvi.Text = o.iName;
            lvi.SubItems.Add(o.iUnit);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(o.iCalories));
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

        }
```

How do I make this into a generic method that doesn't have to know the number of fields.
For example, if i added another field, Category to Ingridient this method wouldn't work.
Would also like to use it for all my listviews, independ on the class and number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Each subitem is a column in the ListView.  Due to this, `myListView` needs to have 3 columns configured based on the above code.

In your example above, `Test` would be in the first column, `1` in the second, and `2` in the third.

Comment: I have made 3 columns via the UI, is this bad?
http://s18.postimage.org/v2odlhmp3/List_View.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In your `ListView` control, you need to set the `View` style to **Details** if you want to see the `SubItems`.

Example:

```
MyListView.View = View.Details;
```

Comment: I got it to work. But how do I change stuff inside the ListView from another class?

Comment: You'd have to write a public method to do what you want inside your class.